# How Do Troops Receivied From Chests Work?

Tags: dragons-of-atlantis

So I just bought a chest with my last ruby, and got 500 Lava Jaws. Now what I was wondering is do I have to upgrade my Garrisons enough to use them or can I just add them to a regiment. Also does same go for all received from a chest. i.e. Colossal Mites, Steel Shard Harriers, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use them. I received 500 fangtooths once and thought I was only at training hbs I was still able to use them. good luck